# Enoent error after retrieving the imagepath from getArguments() method

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, surfaceview

I have the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: mounted/snapit!/Image-4774.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Basically at first I have a gallery where the user clicks an Image. The the image should open in another fragment inside a Gl SurfaceView. Then the user has some buttons and can chose some filters to edit the image. The problem is that the image doesn't appear at all on the SurfaceView.

Here I get the path to the selected image:

```
    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit, container, false);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    imagePath = bundle.getString("Image");

    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions);


    /**
     * Initialise the renderer and tell it to only render when
     * Explicit requested with the RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY option
     */
    mEffectView = (GLSurfaceView) inflate.findViewById(R.id.effectsview);
    mEffectView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    mEffectView.setRenderer(this);
    mEffectView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    mCurrentEffect = R.id.none;
```

I have checked if getArguments and then getString returns the path, and it does, so I don't think there is the problem.

Then I have the following code:

```
private void loadTextures() {
    // Generate textures
    GLES20.glGenTextures(2, mTextures, 0);

    // Load input bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options btmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, btmOptions);
    mImageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    mImageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    mTexRenderer.updateTextureSize(mImageWidth, mImageHeight);

    // Upload to texture
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    // Set texture parameters
    GLToolbox.initTexParams();
}


private void initEffect() {
    EffectFactory effectFactory = mEffectContext.getFactory();
    if (mEffect != null) {
        mEffect.release();
    }
    /**
     * Initialize the correct effect based on the selected menu/action item
     */
    switch (mCurrentEffect) {

        case R.id.none:
            break;
        case R.id.fisheye:
            mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                    EffectFactory.EFFECT_FISHEYE);
            mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
            break;

        case R.id.grain:
            mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                    EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAIN);
            mEffect.setParameter("strength", 1.0f);
            break;

        case R.id.negative:
            mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                    EffectFactory.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
            break;

        case R.id.duotone:
            mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                    EffectFactory.EFFECT_DUOTONE);
            mEffect.setParameter("first_color", Color.YELLOW);
            mEffect.setParameter("second_color", Color.DKGRAY);
            break;

        case R.id.documentary:
            mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                    EffectFactory.EFFECT_DOCUMENTARY);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

private void applyEffect() {
    mEffect.apply(mTextures[0], mImageWidth, mImageHeight, mTextures[1]);
}


private void renderResult() {
    if (mCurrentEffect != R.id.none) {
        // if no effect is chosen, just render the original bitmap
        mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[1]);
    } else {
        saveFrame = true;
        // render the result of applyEffect()
        mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[0]);
    }
}


@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    if (!mInitialized) {
        //Only need to do this once
        mEffectContext = EffectContext.createWithCurrentGlContext();
        mTexRenderer.init();
        loadTextures();
        mInitialized = true;
    }
    if (mCurrentEffect != R.id.none) {
        //if an effect is chosen initialize it and apply it to the texture
        initEffect();
        applyEffect();
    }
    renderResult();
    if (saveFrame) {
        saveBitmap(takeScreenshot(gl));
    }
}


private boolean saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

    boolean status = false;
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageState().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/snapit!");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);

    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        Log.i("TAG", "Image SAVED==========" + file.getAbsolutePath());

        status = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return status;

}

public Bitmap takeScreenshot(GL10 mGL) {
    final int mWidth = mEffectView.getWidth();
    final int mHeight = mEffectView.getHeight();
    IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.allocate(mWidth * mHeight);
    IntBuffer ibt = IntBuffer.allocate(mWidth * mHeight);
    mGL.glReadPixels(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);

    // Convert upside down mirror-reversed button to right-side up normal
    // button.
    for (int i = 0; i < mHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mWidth; j++) {
            ibt.put((mHeight - i - 1) * mWidth + j, ib.get(i * mWidth + j));
        }
    }

    Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ibt);
    return mBitmap;
}


@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig eglConfig) {

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if (mTexRenderer != null) {
        mTexRenderer.updateViewSize(width, height);
    }
}



public void setCurrentEffect(int effect) {
    mCurrentEffect = effect;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    setCurrentEffect(v.getId());
    mEffectView.requestRender();

}
```

At first i was thinking that the images were to big, so I tried with small ones, but no luck..

Comment: If you examine the folder, are the files actually there?

Comment: Yes, there are images in that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some refactoring, and changed some code and now it works. Didn't find out why it didn't work in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that the problem is because you have an exclamation point at the end of your folder name; try it without the ! (`mounted/snapit/Image-4774.jpg`)

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466261/unable-to-open-resources-in-directories-which-end-with-an-exclamation-mark) for explanations.