# Trying to read *.xlsx file using POI API

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

I am trying to read an *.xlsx file and i receive quite a lot of errors in the console. I am a beginner at this and please note that if i try to read *.xls files i have no problems there.

This is the code that i use:

```
    public class XlsxTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("autotest2.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

        for (Row row : sheet) {
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                switch (formulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
                }
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

When i try to run this i receive the following errors:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:465)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:173)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:278)
    at XlsxTest.main(XlsxTest.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:60)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.BuiltinSchemaTypeSystem.fillInType(BuiltinSchemaTypeSystem.java:1025)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.BuiltinSchemaTypeSystem.<clinit>(BuiltinSchemaTypeSystem.java:223)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.getNoType(XmlBeans.java:856)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.<clinit>(XmlBeans.java:881)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:83)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Installation Problem???  Couldn't load messages: Can't find bundle for base name org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.message, locale en_US
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.RegexParser.setLocale(RegexParser.java:88)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.RegexParser.<init>(RegexParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.ParserForXMLSchema.<init>(ParserForXMLSchema.java:28)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.RegularExpression.setPattern(RegularExpression.java:2996)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.RegularExpression.setPattern(RegularExpression.java:3009)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.RegularExpression.<init>(RegularExpression.java:2975)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression.<init>(SchemaRegularExpression.java:27)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression.<init>(SchemaRegularExpression.java:23)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$1.<init>(SchemaRegularExpression.java:44)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression.buildKnownPatternMap(SchemaRegularExpression.java:43)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression.<clinit>(SchemaRegularExpression.java:38)
    ... 19 more
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? I hope that i provided the necessary information.

Thank you!

Comment: it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364338/org-apache-poi-poixmlexception-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-in-p

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, i saw that thread and it doesn't help me. I have a simple xlsx file created using MS Excel with simple text inside.

Comment: share poi jar details.

Comment: i got the latest version available: 

poi-3.13-20150929
I also used the following jars:

poi-ooxml-3.13-20150929
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13-20150929
xmlbeans-2.6.0

Comment: What other xmlbeans jars do you have? Looks to me like you have an older and/or broken copy of xmlbeans as well

Comment: I have nothing else. I downloaded the archive from here https://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.13 which has the xmlbeans jar inside

Comment: It's not about what you downloaded, it's about what you don't know about! Check your whole classpath, including jars provided by your framework

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename jar of lib in zip or simply open org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/regex of loaded lib.
2. Find file message.properties (and message_xx.properties if necessary).
3. Put file(s) in used library by org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/regex path.
4. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the very similar exception when using Apache POI: a java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, caused by "java.lang.RuntimeException: Installation Problem???  Couldn't load messages: Can't find bundle for base name org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.message" in XMLBeans.

Looked completely weird. Code worked on one machine but failed this way on another for no apparent reason.

After LOTS of debugging hours, I found out the reason was COMPLETELY unrelated to Excel, POI or XMLBeans: **my project was located in the folder ending with "!"**. The solution was simply to rename the folder.

I guess the author had something similar happening, and indeed the linked post about Libre Office has nothing to do with this problem. Instead, the linked post should be the following: [Unable to open resources in directories which end with an exclamation mark (!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466261/unable-to-open-resources-in-directories-which-end-with-an-exclamation-mark)

Answer (score 0):

Got this error ONLY in junit test. Application runs perfectly fine. So check your case as well.

For test, following Sarck's suggestion worked. #4 is little confusing. So below is simple process.. works fine for 2.6 version of xmlbeans library.

In your project where this is failing, create a file named `message.properties` under `src/test/resources/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/regex` folder. (`src/test/resources` is typical maven root resource folder). Add following content in that file

```
parser.parse.1=Wrong character.
parser.parse.2=Invalid reference number.
parser.next.1=A character is required after \\.
parser.next.2='?' is not expected.  '(?:' or '(?=' or '(?!' or '(?<' or '(?#' or '(?>'?
parser.next.3='(?<=' or '(?<!' is expected.
parser.next.4=A comment is not terminated.
parser.factor.1=')' is expected.
parser.factor.2=Unexpected end of the pattern in a modifier group.
parser.factor.3=':' is expected.
parser.factor.4=Unexpected end of the pattern in a conditional group.
parser.factor.5=A back reference or an anchor or a lookahead or a lookbehind is expected in a conditional pattern.
parser.factor.6=There are more than three choices in a conditional group.
parser.atom.1=A character in U+0040-U+005f must follow \\c.
parser.atom.2=A '{' is required before a character category.
parser.atom.3=A property name is not closed by '}'.
parser.atom.4=Unexpected meta character.
parser.atom.5=Unknown property.
parser.cc.1=A POSIX character class must be closed by ':]'.
parser.cc.2=Unexpected end of the pattern in a character class.
parser.cc.3=Unknown name for a POSIX character class.
parser.cc.4='-' is invalid here.
parser.cc.5=']' is expected.
parser.cc.6='[' is invalid in a character class.  Write '\\['.
parser.cc.7=']' is invalid in a character class.  Write '\\]'.
parser.cc.8='-' is an invalid character range. Write '\\-'.
parser.ope.1='[' is expected.
parser.ope.2=')' or '-[' or '+[' or '&[' is expected.
parser.ope.3=The range end code point is less than the start code point.
parser.descape.1=Invalid Unicode hex notation.
parser.descape.2=Overflow in a hex notation.
parser.descape.3='\\x{' must be closed by '}'.
parser.descape.4=Invalid Unicode code point.
parser.descape.5=An anchor must not be here.
parser.process.1=This expression is not supported in the current option setting.
parser.quantifier.1=Invalid quantifier. A digit is expected.
parser.quantifier.2=Invalid quantifier. Invalid quantity or a '}' is missing.
parser.quantifier.3=Invalid quantifier. A digit or '}' is expected.
parser.quantifier.4=Invalid quantifier. A min quantity must be <= a max quantity.
parser.quantifier.5=Invalid quantifier. A quantity value overflow.
```

Duplicate this file as `message_en.properties` at same location.

If you are using newer version of xmlbeans jar then get content of this file from [Apache source - replace version in url](https://github.com/apache/xmlbeans/blob/2.6.0/src/typeimpl/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/regex/message.properties)