# windows - User folder with special character -> class.getResource returns null

Tags: java, windows, special-characters

I have a strange problem in Windows with users that have user folder containing special character like `!` .

example folder: `C:\Users\bazinga!`

When I have a user folder like this, and only in this case, `classname.getResource(string path)` or `classname.getResourceAsStream(string path)` always return null.

How can I solve a problem like this? 
I tried ClassLoader but no luck. I prefer not to use absolute path...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is your program running from a jar?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException yes

Comment: It's probably due to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466261/unable-to-open-resources-in-directories-which-end-with-an-exclamation-mark